# PHP + cURL not working

Tags: php, curl

Trying to get the content of the a certain URL using cURL and PHP.
The code is supposed to run on the  sourceforge.net project web hosting server.

code:

```
<?php

function get_data($url)
{
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 10;
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}

$url1 = urlencode("http://www.google.com"); 
$url2 = "http://www.google.com";
$output = get_data($url2);
echo $output;

?>
```

I've checked that cURL is supported. But the above code is not working, the page is loading till timeout with no output. I've tried the encoded url as well. Why?

Error `503 Service Unavailable`. PHP version 5.3.2

Comment: What error are you getting? It might be from your Internet connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I replaced my curl code with yours and its not working. I tried with 'gmail.com' and it showed fine with my code and with yours it gave a '301 Moved' Error.

My Code is as follows:

```
function get_web_page($url)
{
        //echo "curl:url<pre>".$url."</pre><BR>";
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 15,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 15,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects

    );

    $ch      = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $header['errno']   = $err;
    $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;

    //change errmsg here to errno
    if ($errmsg)
    {
        echo "CURL:".$errmsg."<BR>";
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: your code worked for a simple html site, but not for google and gmail! they were just sample sites, what I want to do is get output of a php file!

Comment: One thing I've also noticed when working with cUrl is that it works differently when the URL is redirecting from http to https. You need to make sure that you code can handle this

Answer (score 5):

You might want to use file_get_contents

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');
/some code here if needed/
return $content;
```

You can also set files inside file_get_contents ex:

```
$content = file_get_contents('textfile.txt');
```

More information about the function [file_get_conents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Some info which I noticed when working with cUrl:

**One thing I've also noticed when working with cUrl is that it works differently when the URL has http or https. You need to make sure that you code can handle this**